# SSAS Dimension - genuinely repeated data in 1 column, how to deal?

Tags: duplicates, ssas, dimensions

I have a dimension (DimContact) which looks like this:

```
ContactAlternateKey  ContactDOB  ContactFullName  ContactPostalAddress
12345                17.4.2000    Timo Ohio       17 Blah Street
12346                17.4.2000    Miki Massa      25 Other Street
12347                19.1.1999    Sven Tokio      17 Blah Street
```

I have another Dim which is used for Addresses based on ParcelID (that's the ID for that actual piece of land) which works as planned.  This Dim is populated from free text fields inside the source system, and not as structured as our Parcel data, also, the contactpostaladdress isn't necessarily in our country, so is just there for supporting information, rather than to serve a legitimate purpose.

When I process the Dim WITHOUT the ContactPostalAddress field as an attribute, everything works to plan, however as soon as I use that field too SSAS complains about a duplicate attribute key (which is one of the addresses that has been repeated - but actually the ContactFullName is different (2 people living at the same address), so is genuinely a different record.

Can anyone suggest how to get around this please?  I am confused, as surely there are duplicate ContactDOB's in there too which SSAS is happy to work around.

I am using VS2015 on SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Moments later I had a lightbulb moment - and have implemented a change in the KeyColumns area of the Properties for the ContactPostalAddress.  I have ordered the "Key Columns" with ContactAlternateKey as first on the list and then ContactPostalAddress as second on the list.  This forces SSAS to do a distinct(both columns) when building the table, rather than just a distinct(ContactPostalAddress).  This works a treat and hopefully will help another user in the future.